# How to upload images to a domain at webhost using php?

Tags: php

What should I do if I want to upload an image to a file system such as a folder in my domain? The thing is, I've tried uploading image on a localhost and it works fine but when i did it in my domain it doesn't work anymore. Don't really know what's the problem here. any help will do! Thanks anyway.

```
<form action="adminUploadTry.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" >
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$image_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$image_type = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$image_size = $_FILES['image']['size'];
$image_tmp_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

if($image_name==''){
    echo "You forgot to select an image. Please choose one!";
    exit();
}

else 
move_uploaded_file(image_tmp_name, "/home/stagcon2/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name"); 

    echo "Image Succesfully Uploaded!";
    echo "<img src='/home/stagcon2/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name'>";
}
?>
```

by the way, the problem here is that after i uploaded an image it will say "successfully uploaded" but when I check my folder the image was not saved.

Comment: you added the write permissions to the folder , upload size ?you check for errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forget `$` sign in `image_tmp_name` at

```
move_uploaded_file($image_tmp_name, "/home/stagcon2/public_html/StagConnect/admin/pictures/$image_name");
```

Comment: my bad ! I've been checking for hours and all i have forgot was the $ sign. Anyway ,thanks for helping me find that tiny mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

See if you need to increase the value of upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini :

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```